# Logstash create nested field

Tags: filter, nested, match, logstash

I have some fields from parsed string:
string example:

`"testmessage 10.5 100"`

```
match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:text} %{NUMBER:duraton} %{NUMBER:code)"
```

output will be the

```
    {
       "text": "testmessage",
       "duraton": "10.5",
       "code": "100"
    }
```

But i want to get like this:

```
    {
       "text": "testmessage",
       "values": {
            "duraton": "10.5",
            "code": "100"
       }
    }
```

How to create a field "values" containing nested field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right way:

`%{GREEDYDATA:text} %{NUMBER:[values]duraton:float} %{NUMBER:[values]code:int)`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is:

```
%{NUMBER:[values][duraton]}
```

Note that you can also cast them in logstash:

```
%{NUMBER:[values][duraton]:float}
```

("int" also works).

Comment: I't does not work. I test this in http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/.        And i get this: `10.5 100 =>                                                                 %{NUMBER:[values][duraton]} %{NUMBER:[values][code]}  =>  {
  "[values][duraton]": [
    "10.5"
  ],
  "[values][code]": [
    "100"
  ]
}`

Comment: I believe neither of the two major grok debuggers supports this syntax, but logstash certainly does.  Try it in a simple config of your own.

Comment: With logstash 1.5.4 I get `Grok regexp threw exception {:exception=>"string not matched", :level=>:warn}` when using the nested field syntax. `--configtest` passes. If I change from `%{NUMBER:[foo][bar]}` to `%{NUMBER:foo_bar}`, it works fine, so I know there's nothing wrong with the rest of my expression.

Comment: Also tried converting `foo_bar` into `[foo][bar]` with `mutate` as suggested here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/best-way-to-create-nested-field/26757

Comment: I've made some headway. `grok` and `mutate` will not let you create `[foo][bar]` if `[foo]` previously existed as a string. However, if `[foo][crud]` already existed, it will happily let you add `[foo][bar]`, `[foo][baz]`, etc. It already considers `[foo]` to be an object.

Interestingly, `kv` *will* let you choose a `target` of `[foo]`, even if it previously existing as a string, and nest discovered keys under there.

I will have to look at source code to see if the "conversion" done by `kv` can be writtern into `grok` and `mutate`, too.

Comment: [Here's the code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-kv/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/kv.rb#L245) that coerces the field to a hash. Doesn't preserve the original value, though.